# Where is memset Hiding In VS 2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have installed VS 2015 RC and it's matching SDK in

U:\ => C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10

V:\ => C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0

However, when I link my app, it can't find memset (among others).  So I ran

DUMPBIN /ALL V:\VC\lib\libcmt.lib | grep "memset"

and found no reference to a definition of memset.

Next, I ran the same DUMPBIN on the libcmt.lib in VS 2013 and it listed a reference as

Archive member name at 4F0D32: /39480          f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\SELF_X86\crt\src\build\INTEL\mt_obj\memset.obj

so I'm left wondering why there seems to be no memset in VS 2015's libcmt.lib file.  The documentation for memset says that it is in every runtime library, so I expected to find it in some variation of libcmt, but no luck.  Where might it be hiding?

Comment: BTW. why do you care where ``memset`` is located?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VS 2015 uses the "uCRT" so a number of the CRT function bodies have moved about.

**`memset` is now in `vcruntime.lib`.**

Also `memset` is an intrinsic, so in optimized builds it's typically fully inlined.

See

- [The Great C Runtime (CRT) Refactoring](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/10/the-great-crt-refactoring.aspx)
- [C Runtime (CRT) Features, Fixes, and Breaking Changes in Visual Studio 14 CTP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/18/crt-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx)
- [Introducing the Universal CRT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt.aspx)

Comment: A lot of functions were stripped from static libraries. wcsncmp for example. That makes me crazy...